# JAVA: Choosing algorithm based on multiple dimensions

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have an instance of class Address, which I have to change according to environment:
1) Region: base class with sub-classes RegionA and RegionB
2) Site: base class with sub-classes SiteA, SiteB and SiteC
3) Language: base class with sub-classes LanguageA and LanguageB
Each subclass defines constraints about Address modification.
The problem is that each tuple (Region, Site, Language) has to define its own modifier.

So, I have a method adjust(Address a, Region r, Site s, Language l):

```
void adjust(Address a, Region r, Site s, Language l){  
    if(r instanceof Russia && s instanceof MailRu && Language instanceof Russian){
        a.set_street("abc")
    }
    else if(r instanceof Russia && s instanceof MailRu && Language instanceof English){
        a.set_street("fgh")
    }
}
```

What is the best design patter to use in this case?

Comment: Can you give an example of `adjust()`? when you say "each tuple (Region, Site, Language) has to define its own modifier", do you mean that a tuple modifier is not a combination of each element modifier?

Comment: Modified the question with an example

Answer (score 2):

- Use **polymorphism** to loose the `if`s and `instanceof`s!
- Use the [**abstract factory pattern**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) for easier creation of the street info.

---

`Region` and `Language` are the (sub)products (resp. their factories, when you consider the way I did it), which are used to create the street in `Address`.

```
package address.example;

public class AddressExample
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    LanguageFactoryProvider lfp = new LanguageFactoryProvider.LanguageFactoryProviderImpl();
    RegionFactoryProvider rfp = new RegionFactoryProvider.RegionFactoryProviderImpl();
    AddressProvider provider = new AddressProvider(lfp, rfp);

    Address a = provider.createAddress("RU", "USA", "Famous Street");
    System.out.println(a.getStreet());

    System.out.println("-----");

    Address b = provider.createAddress("EN", "RUS", "Good Street");
    System.out.println(b.getStreet());
  }
}
```

Output is

```
Address format: RU
Famous Street
USA
-----
Address format: EN
Good Street
RUS
```

---

This is the Address class, as you can see it delegates parts of the street creation to `region` and `language` (it's nothing fancy, but you get the point).

```
package address.example;

import address.example.LanguageFactoryProvider.Language;
import address.example.RegionFactoryProvider.Region;

public interface Address
{
  public String getStreet();

  static class AddressImpl implements Address
  {
    private final Region region;
    private final Language language;

    private final String street;

    public AddressImpl(Region region, Language language, String street)
    {
      this.region = region;
      this.language = language;
      this.street = street;
    }

    @Override
    public String getStreet()
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append(String.format("Address format: %s", language.getSpecifier()));
      sb.append(String.format("%n"));
      sb.append(street);
      sb.append(String.format("%n"));
      sb.append(region.getSpecifier());
      return sb.toString();
    }
  }
}
```

And here are the other used classes. I'll add some more thoughts to it another time.

```
package address.example;

import address.example.LanguageFactoryProvider.Language;
import address.example.RegionFactoryProvider.Region;

public class AddressProvider
{
  private final LanguageFactoryProvider lfp;
  private final RegionFactoryProvider rfp;

  public AddressProvider(LanguageFactoryProvider lfp, RegionFactoryProvider rfp)
  {
    this.lfp = lfp;
    this.rfp = rfp;
  }

  public Address createAddress(String language, String region, String street)
  {
    Language _language = lfp.getLanguageFactory(language).createLanguage();
    Region _region = rfp.getRegionFactory(region).createRegion();
    return new Address.AddressImpl(_region, _language, street);
  }
}
```

---

```
package address.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public interface LanguageFactoryProvider
{
  public LanguageFactory getLanguageFactory(String language);

  static interface LanguageFactory
  {
    public Language createLanguage();
  }

  static interface Language
  {
    public String getSpecifier();
  }

  static class LanguageImpl implements Language
  {
    private final String specifier;

    public LanguageImpl(String specifier)
    {
      this.specifier = specifier;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecifier()
    {
      return specifier;
    }
  }

  static class LanguageFactoryProviderImpl implements LanguageFactoryProvider
  {
    private static final Map<String, LanguageFactory> factories = new HashMap<>();
    static
    {
      factories.put("EN", new EnglishLanguageFactory());
      factories.put("RU", new RussianLanguageFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public LanguageFactory getLanguageFactory(String language)
    {
      if (!factories.containsKey(language))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

      LanguageFactory factory = factories.get(language);
      return factory;
    }
  }

  static class RussianLanguageFactory implements LanguageFactory
  {
    @Override
    public Language createLanguage()
    {
      return new LanguageImpl("RU");
    }
  }

  static class EnglishLanguageFactory implements LanguageFactory
  {
    @Override
    public Language createLanguage()
    {
      return new LanguageImpl("EN");
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
package address.example;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public interface RegionFactoryProvider
{
  public RegionFactory getRegionFactory(String region);

  static interface RegionFactory
  {
    public Region createRegion();
  }

  static interface Region
  {
    public String getSpecifier();
  }

  static class RegionImpl implements Region
  {
    private final String specifier;

    public RegionImpl(String specifier)
    {
      this.specifier = specifier;
    }

    @Override
    public String getSpecifier()
    {
      return specifier;
    }
  }

  static class RegionFactoryProviderImpl implements RegionFactoryProvider
  {
    private static final Map<String, RegionFactory> factories = new HashMap<>();
    static
    {
      factories.put("RUS", new RussianRegionFactory());
      factories.put("USA", new UsRegionFactory());
    }

    @Override
    public RegionFactory getRegionFactory(String region)
    {
      if (!factories.containsKey(region))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

      RegionFactory factory = factories.get(region);
      return factory;
    }
  }

  static class RussianRegionFactory implements RegionFactory
  {
    @Override
    public Region createRegion()
    {
      return new RegionImpl("RUS");
    }
  }

  static class UsRegionFactory implements RegionFactory
  {
    @Override
    public Region createRegion()
    {
      return new RegionImpl("USA");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is typical business "logic" with many cases/rules. It pays to make a declarative solution for this.

```
<rule>
    <when category="Region" value="Russia"/>
    <when category="Site" value="MailRu"/>
    <action category="Address" value="abc"/>
</rule>
```

This allows to build in diagnostics, integrity checks, log uncovered cases, make historical logs for future analysis on future bug reports.

It might even be more readable. Transformable in a nice HTML table hierarchy for manager level documentation.

---

It boils down to the fact that your code is procedural, without possibility to store the control-flow path taken. A model-driven approach can alleviate that. A DSL would be feasible, but I find a free form data approach to be a bit more creative, direct.

Comment: +1. Is it possible to set different address formats with your solution? That's what's really interesting. OP just gave a poor example.

Comment: ...yes, it should be :D